# Where should I put a custom method for a existing class in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add a method `nil_or_zero?` to `Object` class in my Rails project.

```
class Object
   def nil_or_zero?
     self.nil? or self == 0
   end
end
```

Where should I put the file for it?
And what name is preferable in rails culture?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? Why not do `pancakes.to_i == 0` instead? Or are you planning on using `nil_or_zero?` on things that might not be numbers?

Comment: I didn't know `nil.to_i` return `0`. Thanks for info! But, I'll use `nil_or_zero?` this time, because the name represents what is the function clearly at least for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails, these types of customizations would go under the `config/initializers` folder so that they are initialized when the Rails server process starts. The name of the file doesn't really matter - you can call it nil_or_zero.rb if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Under the `/config` directory you'll find the `initializers` directory.

Place your file in there, with a representative filename like 'object_patches.rb' or 'nil_or_zero.rb'. Or just 'object.rb'. Whatever makes sense in the context of your app.

If you change this file you will need to restart your server/console/test suite runner. Initializers, as the name suggests, are run when Rails is first started.